# union processed data from DataTables into new one and set the result to RDLC

Tags: c#, database, xsd, rdlc

I want to make a DataTable with data from multiple queries. I will show it at example:
I got a table with data:

```
DataTable1 Column ID, A, B, C
```

And I want to create DataTable2 where I can put Column D with new value="this is table2 rows" but only for first 10 rows where column B is equal to value 5:

```
DataTable2 Column ID, A, B, C, D
```

Then I want to create another DataTable3 with Column D with value="this is table3 rows" but for the first 6 rows but the rows where ID is not in the DataTable2

And so on... Then i want to union all my DataTable:

```
DataTable2 Column ID, A,B,C,D
UNION ALL
DataTable3 Column ID, A,B,C,D
UNION ALL
DataTable4 Column ID, A,B,C,D
```

to DataTable100 and present that result in rdlc. For create DataTable I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 .xsd editor. How can I achieve something like this?

In SQL I could make something like this:

```
select top 10 id, a, b, c, d="table2 rows" into ##temp1 from DataTable1 where b=5;
select top 6 id, a,b,c,d="table3 rows" into ##temp2 from DataTable1 where b=5 and id not in (select id from ##temp1);
select top 2 id, a,b,c,d="table4 rows" into ##temp3 from DataTable1 where b=2 and id not in (select id from ##temp1) and id not in (select id from ##temp2);
```

And so on. But I don't know how to do this in Visual Studio. Can I use something like temporary tables?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/fk68ew7b(v=vs.110).aspx, but maybe it would be easier if you use entity framework and linq.

Comment: Can you give me an example how to use linq for this? I was checking DataTable Merge solution, but I don't know how can it help me to check if data exist in previous table. Merge is like an UNION ALL of two datatables, right? I mean take all data from two DataTables and create a new DataTable from both of this tables? I need to create table2 from table1 and then table3 from table1 but without data which is in table2. And then the same: table4 from table1 whitout data which is in table2 or in table3, etc...